# Unable to create byte[] array of file and vice versa - android

Tags: android

I am unable to create `byte[]` array of file and and re-create `byte[]` to file. File creates from `byte[]` array with exact size what was before, but unable to open it. It say's format is not supported. Like-wise I have to do for more file's like video, audio, docs etc. I have tried answer's available in stack-overflow but no success.

Here is my code:- 
To convert image into `byte[]` array

```
public static byte[] getBytesFromImage() {
FileInputStream in;
    try {
        File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "nature.jpg");
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(photo);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] b = new byte[1024];
        for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
        }
        bMapArray = bos.toByteArray();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bMapArray;
}
```

To convert `byte[]` array into image file.

```
public static String getImageFromBytesTemp() {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "nature2.jpg");
    if (file.exists()) {
        file.delete();
    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos=new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
        fos.write(bMapArray);
        fos.close();
        }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return file.getAbsolutePath();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried converting byte[] to Bitmap?

Comment: @Gotiasits Yes i have tried with Bitmap , No result, same issue occurs.

Comment: Well I just tried it with `bitmap.compress()` and it works fine. Check your logcat. 
Also you get "format not supprted" when you try to open file within your own app or from file manager?

Comment: @Gotiasits From my app and file manager both, i need it to be worked for files like audio, image, video, and docs.

Comment: I have also tried IOUtils and FileUtils . But getting same issue.

Comment: Maybe you hаve a problem with internal indexing. You could give MediaStore a try.

Comment: @Gotiasits Actually file is successfully created in device, I can see it in file-manager with the same size of original one's , but while opening it , i can't. It say's format is not supported, same happens with app.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok,
maybe you simply need to flush your ByteArrayOutputStream

```
for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(b)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(b, 0, readNum);
    }
    bMapArray = bos.toByteArray();

    bos.flush();
    bos.close();
```

Comment: My tip is try with a small file, if it doesn't work open it with a tool that let you compare source and destination file or almost in Hexadecimal.

Comment: I am trying with the smallest file less than 500kb.

Comment: can you check with hex editor where two files differ?